# Dismiss pop-up alert in Python when running subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, error-handling, subprocess, popen

I have a script that runs multiple threads of an external .exe with subprocess.Popen(). Occasionally the subprocess will produce an error pop-up alert with an "OK" button that needs to be dismissed before any other error handling. How can I programmatically "click" the OK button to get the process to continue?

Comment: What type of .exe file is that? It does not seem to be written to be used in an automated flow, or it would not have pop-up errors. Is it a custom made .exe or is it a standardized program?

Comment: I don't think it was originally written to be used in an automated flow. It is a pretty specialized program for use in a small community (remote sensing, satellite imagery analysis). 

Ideally I'd be able to do some pre-processing checks to determine if it would fail, but it is closed source so I can't be sure what exactly is triggering the error.

If you're interested: https://github.com/GERSL/Fmask